# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff522f9e98)

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-access

I am very new to coding and i have decided to begin learning swift.
I have encountered a problem with a bug apparently and my app is not running properly.
I have attached all the code in my project. Hope anyone can help.
Thanks In advance

[ContactsTableViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqmiJ.png)

[ContactsTableViewController2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TelRb.png)

[Contacts.swift (file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQWZA.png)

[StoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qtcrw.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please don't post images. Post text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the lines where object creates inside a class like

```
var thirdContact = Contacts()
```

in Contacts class. You can't create object inside same class, it leads to endless loop. Stack trace example

```
#1  0x000000010b6c3f88 in Contacts.init(name:phone:) at Contacts.swift:12
#2  0x000000010b6c3e11 in Contacts.__allocating_init(name:phone:) ()
#3  0x000000010b6c415a in Contacts.init(name:phone:) at Contacts.swift:22
#4  0x000000010b6c3e11 in Contacts.__allocating_init(name:phone:) ()
#5  0x000000010b6c415a in Contacts.init(name:phone:) at Contacts.swift:22
...
```